# Convert a json to multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-7, jsondecoder

I have the following json sent to my API endpoint

> {"key":"levels","value":"[{role_id:1, access_level_id:3}, {role_id:2, access_level_id:1}, {role_id:3, access_level_id:2}]","description":""}

at the backend, I receive it as a Laravel request as follows:

```
public function functionName(Request $request){
    $req=$request->all();
    Log::debug($req['value']);
    return;
}
```

And it returns the following expected result

> array (
> 'key' => 'levels',
> 'value' => '[{role_id:1, access_level_id:3}, {role_id:2, access_level_id:1}, {role_id:3, access_level_id:2}]',
> 'description' => NULL,
> )

But I need to convert the 'value' to array also. so that I can have a multidimensional PHP array. So I expect to get something like

> array (
> 'key' => 'levels',
> 'value' => array(
> array('role_id'=>1, 'access_level_id'=>3),
> array('role_id'=>2, 'access_level_id'=>1),
> array('role_id'=>3, 'access_level_id'=>2)
> )
> 'description' => NULL,
> )

but when in my Laravel method I do the following:

```
public function share_doc(Request $request){
        $req=$request->all();
        Log::debug(json_decode($req['value'],true));
        return;
    }
```

trying to convert the json received as 'value' to PHP array, it returns nothing -i.e. no value, no array, no string. Just nothing.

So, my struggle here is how I can convert the entire json string received as 'value' from the request to a PHP array so that I can iterate through the items with PHP

Thank you for helping

Comment: Why aren't role_id and access_level_id quoted ? `{"key":"levels","value":[{"role_id":1, "access_level_id":3}, {"role_id":2, "access_level_id":1}, {"role_id":3, "access_level_id":2}],"description":""}` works. Do you have any control over the JSON being created?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Thank you so much. The json has been modified and the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `value` element is not valid JSON as the keys are not quoted. For the sample data you provide, you can fix that with [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and then [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the changed value:

```
$x['value'] = json_decode(preg_replace('/(\w+)(?=:)/', '"$1"', $x['value']), true);
print_r($x);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [key] => levels
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [role_id] => 1
                    [access_level_id] => 3
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [role_id] => 2
                    [access_level_id] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [role_id] => 3
                    [access_level_id] => 2
                )
        )
    [description] => 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HgjJQ)

Comment: Thank you. Quoting the keys within the values resolved the issues

Comment: @Josh it sounds from the comments like you've managed to resolve this at the source of the JSON, which is a much better place to fix it. Hopefully this will be useful to other users with a similar problem.